# On camcorders, are static photos higher quality in video mode or photo mode?

Tags: image-quality, video, sensor-size, hd-video

Camcorders come with photo mode and video mode. But in video mode, you can take a snapshot at any time. Is it guaranteed that the photo mode is using a larger sensor than the sensor size in video mode, or do camcorders use the same sensor size in both modes? Is there a general rule of thumb in the industry that everyone knows  that photos taken in video mode are a big no-no?

Comment: I doubt you can generalise. Camcorders have tiny sensors, so I doubt either would be much good.

Comment: It all depends upon the specific camcorder in question. Maybe even the specific firmware version each of two different samples of the same model are running. As for general rules: It's a fairly universal general rule in the professional imaging industry that using a camcorder to create still images is a **HUGE** *NO-NO*.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is use a stills mode for stills and a video mode for video. Hence the name.

If you’re asking about grandpa’s old Handicam, just test and see what works better for you. This is always the case with *actual* rather than theoretical cameras.

Comment: please reverse the edits. the long write-up was better